# SQL Server 2022 in LXC crashes and won't get back up

Tags: sql-server, lxc, proxmox

I have big scary problem with SQL Server 2022 in LXC containers on PVE.

SQL Server 2019 is working fine in same environment but SQL Server 2022 crashes after few months of working good. After crash it can't be restarted only solution I found is to reinstall the container.

```
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]: This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running at Sun Feb 19 04:30:58 2023
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]: The following diagnostic information is available:
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:          Reason: 0x00000001
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:          Signal: SIGABRT - Aborted (6)
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:           Stack:
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:                  IP               Function
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:                  ---------------- --------------------------------------
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:                  0000562a9b7549d2 <unknown>
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:                  0000562a9b7543f0 <unknown>
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:                  0000562a9b753a8f <unknown>
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:                  00007f093a98f090 killpg+0x40
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:                  00007f093a98f00b gsignal+0xcb
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:                  00007f093a96e859 abort+0x12b
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:                  0000562a9b70ec26 <unknown>
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:                  0000562a9b78576a <unknown>
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:         Process: 4857 - sqlservr
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:          Thread: 4862 (application thread 0x8)
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:     Instance Id: 1f101619-527d-4094-ac00-c2b857339367
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:        Crash Id: 8b1a4608-d26c-421a-beff-e83d1f30b91f
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:     Build stamp: 7381104a7baabc096c65c6cf9b3c3c2c36e1f155ac27f817e87fab585602cb5f
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:    Distribution: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:      Processors: 2
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:    Total Memory: 67350208512 bytes
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:       Timestamp: Sun Feb 19 04:30:58 2023
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]:      Last errno: 2
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4857]: Last errno text: No such file or directory
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4855]: Capturing a dump of 4857
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4855]: FAILED to capture a dump. Details in paldumper log.
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4855]: Executing: /opt/mssql/bin/handle-crash.sh with parameters
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4855]:      handle-crash.sh
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4855]:      /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4855]:      4857
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4855]:      /opt/mssql/bin
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4855]:      /var/opt/mssql/log/
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4855]:
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4855]:      1f101619-527d-4094-ac00-c2b857339367
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4855]:      8b1a4608-d26c-421a-beff-e83d1f30b91f
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4855]:
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4855]:
Feb 19 04:30:58 sqll sqlservr[4855]: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
```

This probably needs attention from somebody in msft.

Related reports:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/8525

https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/sqlserver-2022-lxc.120898/

Comment: If you check the files in `/var/opt/mssql/log/` do any of them contain text similar to `This is an evaluation version. There are [nnn] days left in the evaluation period`? How big was `nnn`?

Comment: nope.
/var/opt/mssql/log# grep -rni "evaluation" *   -  returns nothing

Comment: It's developer edition btw.